# Monitoring in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I guess I'm a little confused what's going on here.
In phpmyadmin in the Status->Monitor section, when my website
is not even doing anything sql based at the time, I'm getting 6000 questions and 200 connections.

This very much does not seem normal, can anyone give me some tips about what's really going on here, this can't be normal, right?

edit:
Im trying to connect to about four different tables every five seconds and pull information from them, and I believe it's causing my server to crash. Is this a bad parctice?

I'm using jquery and php. I think even through bad programming I can't be hitting the 400 queries a second phpmyadmin is saying I'm hitting.

Comment: Is your website on a shared platform?

Comment: I'm using hosting24, I can only see my databses, is it possible that I'm sharing the server with a grip of other people?

Comment: If you got the silver or gold package, jup, you do share resources with other websites. Unless you go with your own server (like VPS) you will see the count of queries and connections ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be able to see which queries are running from Status > Monitor, in a particular time range taken from the moving graph. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZRZoCsrKis  starting at 6:00.

Comment: I tried that earlier and I just got "no data found" kinda error =/

Comment: Are you sure you followed "Instructions/Setup" ?

Comment: I didn't set up my phpmyadmin, turns out I'm on a shared server, and my CPU limit is way too low for what I want to do, so I'm setting up a dedicated serer right now