# Does "Questions" means "queries" in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, monitor

I'm working on improvements for my database and I would like to be sure of the meaning of one chart's legend. When I go to Status>Monitor in phpMyAdmin, there is a chart with a metric named "Questions". **Does "Questions" means "queries"?**

I tried to find a definition in the official documentation, but I didn't find anything!(http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/)

[image: phpMyAdmin - screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Monitoring in PhpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621146/monitoring-in-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you [Pankaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3583971/pankaj) for your help!

**"Questions" means "queries"!!!**

As explained in this [tutorial at Debconf13 on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZRZoCsrKis&feature=youtu.be&t=6m)

Comment: I have never found out if "1000 questions" means: 1000 concurrent queries in the moment OR 1000 queries per second OR 1000 queries per minute OR whatever...

Comment: I also wonder this, did you get any info regarding this yet?